# How to get values when a single array has multiple array into it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a unique problem that within `foreach` i get an array which keeps showing multiple values due to `foreach` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)

Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)

Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)

Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)

Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)

Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)
```

Now the problem is that I can not take out this array out of foreach and want an array of values with a unique key.
Is it possible to get a single array out of it with a unique key?
Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: `$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input))); and then foreach ($input as $inpu){echo $inpu[0];}`

Comment: i have created a function $inno = $this->wgGetInno($inid, NULL, 1); and i call it into foreach, due which it showing array in above mentioned way. Moreove, i have to use it within foreach not before foreach.

Comment: How could i get value for this array 
Array
(
    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
        )

)